# Аналог synchronized

Tags: java, многопоточность, очередь

Имеется таск. Нужно реализовать многопоточное приложение, без использования synchronized.

Есть порт с причалами(1 причал - 1 корабль). Есть корабли с грузом и склад.
В причале корабль может перенести груз в склад либо на другой корабль.

Я пробовал просто в каждой функции ставить в начале и конце ReentrantLock. Видимо, я плохо понял как он работает. С synchronized можно просто навесить его на каждый трэд, который первым приходит в функцию и всё работает на ура, а без него - тупик. Может кто подсказать как же правильно использовать lock или другой способ реализации такого приложения?

[GitHub](https://github.com/immraytal/task3)

Кусок кода:

```
private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public boolean tryTransfer(Ship ship) {// ф-ия пытается добавить груз(cargo)  в хранилище
    boolean flag;                      // capacity - объём хранилища
    lock.lock();

    if (capacity + ship.getCargo()>maxCapacity) { 
        flag = false;
    } else
    {
        capacity+=ship.getCargo();
        ship.setCargo(0);

        flag = true;
    }
         lock.unlock();
        return flag;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы привели свой код с `ReentrantLock`

Comment: добавил кусочек кода

Comment: `lock.unlock();` надо делать в секции `try-finally` иначе он может не произойти

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/locks-concurrent/reentrantlock/java-reentrantlock-example/

Comment: не сработало, добавил гит хаб на всякий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы часто создаёте `ReentrantLock` внутри методов и там же их используете (это видно в классах `Dock` и `Ship`). Это не имеет никакого смысла, если эти Lock'и вы не передаёте куда-либо ещё. Храните `ReentrantLock` в полях.
2. Ваша реализация `Storage#tryTransfer` (та, что на GitHub, а не здесь) почти корректная. Вы правильно ограничиваете доступ к данным самого `Storage`. Однако в этом методе вы неправильно работаете с `Ship` - методы `Ship#getCargo` и `Ship#setCargo` не являются синхронизированными.
   В данном случае вам нужно брать блокировку и в `Storage`, и `Ship`. Примерно так (по аналогии можете переделать и всё остальное):

   ```
   public class Ship {
       private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
       private double cargo;

       public double getCargo() {
           this.lock.lock();
           try {
               return this.cargo;
           } finally {
               this.lock.unlock();
           }
       }

       public void setCargo(double cargo) {
           this.lock.lock();
           try {
               this.cargo = cargo;
           } finally {
               this.lock.unlock();
           }
       }

       public ReentrantLock getLock() {
           return this.lock;
       }
   }

   public class Storage {
       private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
       private final double maxCapacity = 100;
       private double capacity;

       public boolean tryTransfer(Ship ship) {
           this.lock.lock();
           try {
               ship.getLock().lock();
               try {
                   if (this.capacity + ship.getCargo() > this.maxCapacity) {
                       return false;
                   }

                   this.capacity += ship.getCargo();
                   ship.setCargo(0);
               } finally {
                   ship.getLock().unlock();
               }

               return true;
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } finally {
               this.lock.unlock();
           }

           return false;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Зачем в пункте #2 в `Storage#tryTransfer` я дополнительно брал блокировку над `Ship#getLock`, если она уже была в `Ship#getCargo` и `Ship#setCargo`? Дело в том, что возможна ситуация, когда одновременно несколько потоков будут работать с одним и тем же экземпляром `Ship`. Т.е. мы вызвали `Ship#getCargo` и получили, например, 10. И ожидаем, что, когда мы вызовем `Ship.setCargo(0)`, cargo всё ещё будет равен 10. Однако без дополнительной синхронизации между нашими вызовами `Ship#getCargo` и `Ship#setCargo` какой-нибудь другой поток может сам вызвать `Ship#setCargo` с каким-нибудь другим значением, и получится, что в момент нашего вызова `Ship#setCargo(0)` cargo равен не 10, как было изначально, а например, 12.

UPDATE

1. В `Ship#run` вы забываете взять блокировку у `Dock` при работе с ним.
2. В `Ship#run` вы вызываете `ReentrantLock#lock` внутри `try-finally`, а не до него. Так делать нельзя, так как есть риск, что `try-finally` прервётся (например, из-за исключения) до взятия блокировки, а `ReentrantLock#unlock` всё равно будет вызван.
3. Зачем в `Ship#run` вы вызываете `Dock#setCurrentShip`? Не лучше просто положить `Ship` в `Dock#shipsQueue`, а дальше причал сам разберётся, какой корабль обработать в первую очередь?
4. В `Dock#run` после вызова `ReentrantLock#lock` сразу делайте `try-finally`. Исключение может произойти даже в обычном `System.out.println()`, из-за чего ваш `ReentrantLock#unlock` не будет вызван.
5. Если работаете с какими-то данными, то сразу берите блокировку. Например, в `Dock#run` вы сперва проверяете `Dock#currentShip` и только потом берёте блокировку. И то не всегда. Если бы `Dock#currentShip` не торчал наружу, то это было бы нормально, но ведь у вас есть `Dock#getCurrentShip` и `Dock#setCurrentShip`, что означает необходимость их синхронизации.
6. Чисто архитектурный недочёт: уберите `Dock#setShipsQueue`. Не дело, когда кто угодно может взять и просто так подменить столь важную коллекцию. Лучше вообще её создавать внутри `Dock` (а не принимать снаружи) и никому не отдавать - просто добавить публичные `Dock#addShip` и `Dock#removeShip`. Ну и `Dock#isFree` можно модифицировать, чтобы он не значение какого-то поля возвращал, а проверял `Dock#currentShip` и `Dock#shipsQueue` (хотя тут уже решайте сами - ваша изначальная задумка мне неизвестна).
7. `Dock#isFree` всегда будет возвращать `false` после первой обработки любого непустого корабля. Мне кажется, тут что-то не так - корабли когда-нибудь закончатся => причал должен в таком случае стать пустым, чего не происходит.

UPDATE

1. Перед вызовом `ReentrantLock#unlock` не нужно вызывать `ReentrantLock#tryLock`. Поток уже владеет блокировкой, так что такая проверка ничего не даст.
2. В `Ship#run` у вас происходит бесконечное добавление корабля в очередь. Просто уберите цикл, он не нужен.
3. Новая реализация `Storage#run` совершенно некорректна. Даже если опустить пункт #1, вы зачем-то освобождаете блокировки перед `return` и тому подобными операторами. В этом нет никакой необходимости - блок `finally` выполняется всегда, даже после `return` или `continue`.
4. Вы не учли пункт #5 из предыдущего обновления ответа.

Comment: Пункт #3 несколько запутанно расписал. Вот более простое и короткое объяснение:
Да, `Ship#getCargo` и `Ship#setCargo` синхронизированы и могут одновременно выполняться только одним потоком, однако между вызовами может влезть кто угодно. Чтобы это не произошло, мы и завернули их в ещё одну блокировку.

Comment: всё очень круто расписано и рассказано, спасибо
как-то что-то поменял и на первый взгляд всё заработало, но как сделал 1 док и 5 кораблей показало, что все корабли кидают себя в currentShip в доке по очереди, а отрабатывает только 1
не могу понять в чём проблема, гитхаб обновил

Comment: Всё ещё есть проблемы с использованием блокировок. Да и чисто архитектурные просчёты (хотя на работоспособность в данном случае они не влияют, но просто принять к сведению стоит). Так как я не знаю, что в конечном итоге должна делать ваша программа, то точное решение подсказать не могу. Впрочем, одна только реализация нового третьего пункта (путём комментирования прямой работы с причалом) привела к, предположительно, более правильному поведению - корабли сбросили весь свой груз на склад.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо, сейчас всё переделаю. 
Понравилась идея с простой отсылкой кораблей в очередь, а причалы сами возьмут себе корабль. Вот только думаю, как реализовать такую штуку. Создал 2 метода `Dock#addShip` и `Dock#removeShip` , вот только получается нужно каждому доку передавать в его собсвтенную очередь этот корабль. А что если создать отдельный класс или вписать в склад например эту самую очередь и просто её менять. Так будет хорошо?

Comment: Дико извиняюсь за наглость, но не могли бы вы взглянуть на новый код(тот же гит, ветка - another_queue), при дебаге останавливается на lock(), в чём может быть причина?

Comment: Исправьте пункты #1..3. После этого всё заработает.

Comment: И нет, очередь, как мне кажется, нужно именно для причалов, а не для склада. Иначе получится, что к одному причалу может становиться бесконечное количество кораблей, а ждать они будут именно при работе со складом.
Кроме того корабль не нужно добавлять ко всем причалам сразу. Он ведь чисто физически не может разделиться. Впрочем, можно сделать "диспетчера", в очередь которого корабли будут себя добавлять, а дальше он сам будет искать наименее загруженные причалы и отправлять к ним корабли.

Comment: Да, согласен со всеми пунктами, вроде как-то криво, но работает, остальное, думаю, сам смогу доделать.
Спасибо огромное за такой большой труд и уделённое время. Снимаю шляпу